# Swift: Convert a Sync function to Async

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

If you have a sync function, how would you convert it to an async function?

```
func syncFunc() -> Int {
    //Do something
}
```

Would this work?

```
func asyncFunc(_ syncFunc:()->Int, _ completion:(Int)->()) -> Int {
    DispatchQueue.background.async{
        completion( syncFunc() )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, functions containing an asynchronous task cannot return any value from the closure body and both closures must be marked as `@escaping`

```
func asyncFunc(_ syncFunc: @escaping ()->Int, completion: @escaping (Int)->()) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        completion( syncFunc() )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to add @escaping for the syncFunc? What happens if we run it without making syncFunc @escaping?

Comment: The compiler throws an error without the `@escaping` directive.

Comment: You need to add `@escaping` as the `syncFunc` parameter will exist after the `asyncFunc` has returned.  `asyncFunc` is adding `syncFunc` to an asynchronous queue to be run at some future point.  if you want a return value you will need to pass it into the completion handler and deal with it there.